# Java printer api

Tags: java, swing, printing, awt, components

I want develop a stand alone application for a medical store with Java Swing. There is a mandatory requirement of printing of a sheet with a small size (219mm to 140mm) with a single click without the print dialog. Intermittently they need to take reports to full A4 pages from a different printer.

Is it possible to change printer and paper properties in a Java application with Java SE without bringing the printer dialog ?

Answer (score 1):

An example from javadoc of `PrintService` interface

```
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.POSTSCRIPT;
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
PrintService[] pservices =
              PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, aset);
if (pservices.length > 0) {
    DocPrintJob pj = pservices[0].createPrintJob();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.ps");
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, null);
        pj.print(doc, aset);
     } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
     } catch (PrintException e) {
     }
}
```

You can get all available PrintServices and print with desired format.